# Apache2: problems with Arabic filenames (404)

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding, apache2, arabic

I have an apache2 server which archives content (news) downloaded from the web with wget. Some URL contain Arabic characters and are downloaded with weird encoding such as the following,

`72101-%D9%81%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%AF-%D8%AD%DA%A9%D9%88%D9%85%D8%AA%DB%8C%D8%8C-%DA%AF%D9%86%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D9%86%D8%B8%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A2%D8%AE%D9%88%D9%86%D8%AF%DB%8C.html`

Although I use the `--restrict-file-names=nocontrol` parameter with `wget`, but somehow it doesn't seem to apply when URLs are in a file that `wget` accesses with -i option).

The problem is that when accessing these files on my server, apache2 seems to try to reencode these filenames in Arabic when processing the URL, looks for an URL in Arabic, and then complains that it doesn't find the files and returns a 404 error...

I am fine with these files having weird names, I just want Apache to stop reencoding the URLs - they should point to the following,

`72101-%D9%81%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%AF-%D8%AD%DA%A9%D9%88%D9%85%D8%AA%DB%8C%D8%8C-%DA%AF%D9%86%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D9%86%D8%B8%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A2%D8%AE%D9%88%D9%86%D8%AF%DB%8C.html`, not 
72101-فساد-حکومتی،-گنداب-نظام-آخوندی.html
which does not exist.

Is there a way to have apache2 stop doing that?